# How to authenticate into AWS ECR in Kubernetes Yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have the following `pod.yaml` file that simply describes the creation of a Kubernetes pod:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dotnet-console-producer-poc.pod
  labels:
    app: helloworld
spec:
  containers:
  - name: dotnet-console-producer-pod
    image: 442285873998.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dotnet-console-producer-benchmark-docker:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8001
```

The image referenced is in AWS ECR (`442285873998.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dotnet-console-producer-benchmark-docker:latest`).

When running the create resource command (`kubectl create -f pod.yaml`), the pod gets created but it crashes because it cannot access the image from AWS ECR.  The Kubernetes error is shown below:

```
Failed to pull image "442285873998.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mcflow-dotnet-console-producer-benchmark-docker:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for 442285873998.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mcflow-dotnet-console-producer-benchmark-docker, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: User: arn:aws:sts::607546651489:assumed-role/nodes.dev.vet-dev.digitalecp.mcd.com/i-055276c817ba7a096 is not authorized to perform: ecr:BatchGetImage on resource: arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:442285873998:repository/mcflow-dotnet-console-producer-benchmark-docker
```

My Kubernetes instance is running on an EC2 instance. How can I authenticate into ECR so that Kubernetes can retrieve the image and run it in the pod?

Comment: Oh Man, you can have hundreds of possible errors here, but lets start here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-ecr-troubleshooting/

Comment: The typical way ECR permission are granted to EKS is via an instance profile on the ec2 nodes within the cluster. Did you manually provision the nodes or did you use EKS node groups?

Answer (score 1):

We have created a Helm chart to solve this problem, hope this helps - https://github.com/relizaio/helm-charts/#1-ecr-regcred